My volume control keeps reverting to maximum on connection/disconnection of headphones. How do i stop this?
When ever I connect or disconnect my headphones the volume control changes to maximum level regardless of what levels the headphones and/or main speaker were set to.
This has not always been the case and has only started recently.
This is becoming harmful because I'm being subjected to noise levels that are through the roof.
The system appears to be using pulseaudio but I see the pipewire & pipewire-media-session services are also loaded (but are sleeping).  Could I have a conflict here?
Is there a way I can have the audio system honor my audio level selections?

What version of Ubuntu are you running?

@WinEunuuchs2Unix
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy
